# How can I run command line FFMPEG and accept multiple pipes (video and audio) without blocking on the first input?

Tags: java, android, linux, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to mux h264 and aac created with MediaCodec using FFMPEG, and also use FFMPEG's RTMP support to send to youtube.  I've created two pipes, and am writing from java (android) through WriteableByteChannels.  I can send to one pipe just fine (accepting null audio) like this:

```
./ffmpeg -f lavfi -i aevalsrc=0 -i "files/camera-test.h264" -acodec aac -vcodec copy -bufsize 512k -f flv "rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/XXXX"
```

YouTube streaming works perfectly (but I have no audio).  Using two pipes this is my command:

```
./ffmpeg \
-i "files/camera-test.h264" \
-i "files/audio-test.aac" \
-vcodec copy \
-acodec copy \
-map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 \
-f flv "rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/XXXX""
```

The pipes are created with mkfifo , and opened from java like this:

```
pipeWriterVideo = Channels.newChannel(new FileOutputStream(outputFileVideo.toString()));
```

The order of execution (for now in my test phase) is creation of the files, starting ffmpeg (through adb shell) and then starting recording which opens the channels.  ffmpeg will immediately open the h264 stream and then wait, since it is reading from the pipe the first channel open (for video) will successfully run.  When it comes to trying to open the audio the same way, it fails because ffmpeg has not actually started reading from the pipe.  I can open a second terminal window and cat the audio file and my app spits out what i hope is encoded aac, but ffmpeg fails, usually just sitting there waiting.  Here is the verbose output:

```
ffmpeg version N-78385-g855d9d2 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg
developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
  configuration: --prefix=/home/dev/svn/android-ffmpeg-with-rtmp/src/ffmpeg/android/arm 
    --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-doc --disable-ffplay 
    --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffserver --disable-symver 
    --cross-prefix=/home/dev/dev/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- 
    --target-os=linux --arch=arm --enable-cross-compile 
    --enable-librtmp --enable-pic --enable-decoder=h264 
    --sysroot=/home/dev/dev/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-19/arch-arm 
    --extra-cflags='-Os -fpic -marm' 
    --extra-ldflags='-L/home/dev/svn/android-ffmpeg-with-rtmp/src/openssl-android/libs/armeabi ' 
    --extra-ldexeflags=-pie --pkg-config=/usr/bin/pkg-config
  libavutil      55. 17.100 / 55. 17.100
  libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
  libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
 matched as AVOption 'debug' with argument 'verbose'.
Trailing options were found on the commandline.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option async (audio sync method) with argument 1.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input file files/camera-test.h264.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: files/camera-test.h264.
[file @ 0xb503b100] Setting default whitelist 'file'
```

I think if I could just get ffmpeg to start listening to both pipes, the rest would work out!

Thanks for your time.

EDIT:
I've made progress by decoupling the audio pipe connection and encoding, but now as soon as the video stream has been passed it errors on audio.  I started a separate thread to create the WriteableByteChannel for audio and it never gets passed the FileOutputStream creation.

```
matched as AVOption 'debug' with argument 'verbose'.
Trailing options were found on the commandline.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input file files/camera-test.h264.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: files/camera-test.h264.
[file @ 0xb503b100] Setting default whitelist 'file'
[h264 @ 0xb503c400] Format h264 probed with size=2048 and score=51
[h264 @ 0xb503c400] Before avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 0 bytes read:15719 seeks:0
[h264 @ 0xb5027400] Current profile doesn't provide more RBSP data in PPS, skipping
[h264 @ 0xb503c400] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5000000 microseconds st:0
[h264 @ 0xb503c400] After avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 545242 bytes read:546928 seeks:0 frames:127
Input #0, h264, from 'files/camera-test.h264':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0, 127, 1/1200000: Video: h264 (Baseline), 1 reference frame, yuv420p(left), 854x480 (864x480), 1/50, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 50 tbc
Successfully opened the file.
Parsing a group of options: input file files/audio-test.aac.
Applying option vcodec (force video codec ('copy' to copy stream)) with argument copy.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: files/audio-test.aac.
Unknown decoder 'copy'
[AVIOContext @ 0xb5054020] Statistics: 546928 bytes read, 0 seeks
```

Here is where I attempt to open the audio pipe.

```
new Thread(){
     public void run(){
          Log.d("Audio", "pre thread");
          FileOutputStream fs = null;
          try {
               fs = new FileOutputStream("/data/data/android.com.android.grafika/files/audio-test.aac");
          } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
          }
          Log.d("Audio", "made fileoutputstream");  //never hits here
          mVideoEncoder.pipeWriterAudio = Channels.newChannel(fs);
          Log.d("Audio", "made it past opening audio pipe");
     }
}.start();
```

Thanks.

Comment: do you need to pair the `-acodec ... -i filename -vcodec -i filename`? . Also in the verbose output, can you wrap the config line per `--option`, very hard to read. Good luck.

Comment: I don't think so, I've seen many examples with codec flags at the end.  I just tried it and I get the same output.  I wonder If i need to try streaming the audio and video channels completely independently (maybe if an active video stream is present on the first pipe it will proceed to the second??).  I will try to adapt my code for this.

Comment: As you haven't had any real responses, I would look for websites that are more specific to audio processing or even ffmpeg specific. I'm pretty sure there is an "official" ffmpeg forum where you may get an definitive answer. Thanks for the edit. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your explanation isn't very clear, I can see you're trying to explain exactly what you're doing, but it's not working.

First: can you describe the *actual issue*. I have to read until halfway your post into an 8-line paragraph and it looks like you're suggesting ffmpeg is **hanging**. Is that the issue? You really want to be explicit about that.

Secondly: how do you pipe data into the FIFOs? This matters. Your post is entirely unclear, you seem to suggest ffmpeg reads an entire video file and then moves to the audio. Is that correct? Or are both streams fed to ffmpeg concurrently?

Lastly: if ffmpeg hangs, it's likely because one of your input pipes is blocking (you're pushing data to FIFO-1 and the buffer is full, but ffmpeg wants data from FIFO-2 and the buffer is empty). Both FIFOs need to always be independently filled with data.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, sorry for I was unclear. I think I have two issues, but they are probably related. 1: I cannot open the audio FIFO, 2: ffmpeg is stalling looking at the video FIFO.  The process is (was) launch ffmpeg with the command above, then open FIFO's for writing (video first, then audio) in the application.  I *think* ffmpeg expects video data in the pipe before moving on to the second input.  I am currently working on decoupling the encoder code so that I can immediately write video to the pipe (i'll worry about sync later).  Does that clear anything up?

Comment: Not really. You're still talking about individual FIFOs as if you're filling them one by one. You shouldn't. Both FIFOs must always be continuously filled with data, independently (i.e. typically threaded or so).

Comment: The reason i'm talking about them independently is that I'm not able to open up the second FIFO for writing until something is reading from it.  If i type in 'cat files/audio.mp4' in a second terminal and then start my Android code I can open both fileoutputstreams, but if there is nothing currently listening (for audio) it will not allow me to open the fileoutputstream.  Do I need to create the FIFO differently? PS: I edited the answer with some new info.

Comment: Unknown decoder 'copy' - suggests that you're placing -c:v (or -vcodec) before the last -i argument, which means it's applied to input, not output. What's the exact ffmpeg commandline you're using?

Comment: Thanks, I had started using what shellter had advised above instead of the original command.  I'm able to open and start writing to both pipes now, but it stops writing after a few seconds.  I think this issue is on the java side now.  Should I mark this as the answer or wait until I fix everything?  Also is it appropriate to update the question with the newest information (removing old potentially less useful info), or should I keep the history of the question intact?

Comment: That's very meta, I don't really know :). I'd suggest to keep history of the question as-is. If the new information is related, we can continue the discussion here, else maybe just start a new question otherwise stackoverflow would become very spaghetti, if you know what I mean.

Comment: Thanks Ronald,  I am now able to stream from two pipes.  I think my aac encoding is bonkers, but I substituted it with 16 bit pcm and encoded to aac within ffmpeg and I was able to stream with audio to YouTube just fine.  You really helped me out!

Comment: @Version135b I'm having the same problem, could you share your solution in a gist?